# Jquery UI Tabs Load and select

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-tabs

I'm using JQuery UI Tabs.
I'm navigating on a button click. 
I have 3 tabs. On button click the other two gets activated.
Each tab is a separate jsp file integrated into a single jsp which have tabContainer.

tabNavigationLInk contains the links for jsp loading from controller.

on button click i have

```
  1.  $("#planningTabContainer").tabs().tabs({disabled: []});
  2.  $('#ui-tabs-2').load("/Plan"+tabNavigationLinks[1]);
  3.  $("#planningTabContainer").tabs("select", "#ui-tabs-2");
```

Now the problem is that if i Use the line 3 code, The call on load of JSP is happening twice.
If i don't use the 3rd line code. The tab will get loaded but won't be selected.

Does any one has any solution for this.
Selecting a tab without using the "select". So that the call won't happen twice.

Comment: I didn't quite resolved it but got around by making the "cache" property to true, so whenever i wanted to refresh the tab i'll use $('#ui-tabs-2').load("/Plan"+tabNavigationLinks[1]); otherwise i'll use $("#planningTabContainer").tabs("select", "#ui-tabs-2");
Hope this help someone.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I didn't quite resolved it but got around by making the 
"cache" property to true, so whenever i wanted to refresh the tab i'll use

```
  $('#ui-tabs-2').load("/Plan"+tabNavigationLinks[1]);
```

otherwise i'll use

```
  $("#planningTabContainer").tabs("select", "#ui-tabs-2");
```

Hope this help someone.